# Using quarto in RStudio to generate tufte book with context engine

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, quarto, tufte

I have been trying the `tufte` handbook style on RStudio using the `skeleton.Rmd` script. It works ok excepting the `[@R-base]` side citation that sets cursive for the rest of document probably because of bad format in reference. Other than that, it works nicely. As I am not very experienced in TeX output in Rmarkdown, I would like to know if the Tufte format is necessarily linked to `LaTeX` and `xelatex` engine, or using the `ConText` engine can manage it and I could use `ConText` engine in Quarto to generate Tufte formatted document with Tex output. I'm using Quarto with `context` engine to write a technical book and that option would be so nice. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tufte styles use the [tufte LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex); they cannot be used with ConTeXt.

There are very few (if any) predefined styles for ConTeXt, so you'd have to build this yourself. The only help I can offer is to link [this ConTeXt template](https://github.com/openjournals/inara/blob/main/data/templates/default.context), which might contain a few pointers on how to build a suitable ConTeXt pandoc template.

Comment: Seems like a daunting task for a newcomer to ConTeXt, I guess I'll stick to LaTeX when I need that tufte style and use ConTeXt for other tasks, try to learn it little by little. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Most welcome. The missing support for ConTeXt is a shame, it's such a nice system. It's also currently the best bet if one aims to produce accessible (tagged) PDFs.

Comment: I have an additional comment here. Searching a bit more, I have found that quarto is able to do a tufte-like formatting by itself, using code chunks to position format. Those two links may be useful:
[Quarto: Positioning Content in the margin](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2022-02-17-advanced-layout/#margin-figures)
[A Quarto Page Layout Example](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-gallery/page-layout/tufte.html)